# IF/AND Google Sheets error

Tags: if-statement, syntax, google-sheets, logical-operators

I'm trying to create an IF Statement on Sheets so that if at least one of the last 3 columns (W,X,Y) contains 'YES' then column Z will say 1. If all of them are empty or contain 'NO' then column Z will say 'FALSE' or 'NO'.

Please see what I have below, each time I do it, it only takes the data from W and ignores X and Y.

```
=IF(W3='DATA VALIDATION'!B2,
  1,
  AND(X3='DATA VALIDATION'!B2,1,AND(Y3='DATA VALIDATION'!B2,1,))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a countif across W:Y to see if there is a *Yes*. Any result greater than *0* will ring true in an if. A formula for Z2 would be:

```
=if(countif(W2:Y2, "Yes"), 1, "No")
```

Fill or drag the formula down as necessary.

Comment: For an array-enabled version (e.g. the rows 2 to 100) of the same formula .. =ArrayFormula(if(countif(if(W2:Y100="Yes",row(W2:W100),), row(W2:W100)), 1, "No"))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  =if(or(W3="YES",X3="YES",Y3="YES"),1,"NO")
```

You can replace each instance of "YES" with 'DATA VALIDATION'!B2 as in your original equation.