# How can I create a formula for if statements between 2 cells in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm trying to have 2 IF formula's do something like this:

1. =IF(cell "" = 0, cell "" = 0)
2. =IF(cell "" > 0, cell "" = (cell * cell * cell)

The intention is to automatically disengage a value in a cell from a separate equation if $0 and to include the value if the separate cell is greater than $0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF/AND Google Sheets error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694465/if-and-google-sheets-error)

Comment: Chris, did you use the right tags on this? maybe you meant `google-spreadsheet` instead of a R programming language package (`r-googlesheets`) and the Google Sheets REST API (`google-sheets-api`)... I'll edit for you. If I'm wrong, please specify a LOT more detail on how you are actually using those resources in your task. If I'm right, it's still not totally clear what you mean. Showing an example would help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response- and for updating the tags! it is for Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

In other cell something of this kind:

```
=if(or(cell="",cell=0),0,IF(cell>0,cell^3,"TBD"))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add more ifs I have something that might work for you. Its a measure of how something is being handled based on a time value percentage. 0 in the reference cells makes it to be 'ended' and the other values change according.

```html
=IF(K1=0, "ended",IF(AND(K1>=0.000001, K1<0.49),"on time", IF(AND(K1>=0.5, K1<0.75),"Pending", iF(AND(K1>=0.75, K1<1), "Retard",iF(AND(K1>=1), "Out of time", "Undefined")))))
```